# Populating values not explicitly stated in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add missing column values to a dataframe based off list of possible values.
the list of values looks like:

```
type = ['type1','type2','type3','type4']
```

Here's code for df:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    '1': ['fall',  'type2', 'MATH 1234', 'Yes'],
    '2': ['fall',  'type1', 'MATH 1234', 'Yes']
}
columns=['term', 'type', 'course', 'offered']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    data=data, orient='index'
)
df.columns = columns
```

dataframe looks like:

```
    term    type    course  offered
1   fall    type2   MATH 1234   Yes
2   fall    type1   MATH 1234   Yes
```

desired output:

```
    term    type    course  offered
1   fall    type2   MATH 1234   Yes
2   fall    type1   MATH 1234   Yes
3   fall    type3   MATH 1234   NO
4   fall    type4   MATH 1234   NO
```

type3 and type4 are not offered for MATH 1234 in the fall therefore offered should be "NO".

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: your initial dataframe output is different from the code you shared

Comment: Editted to show exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create all combinations of `term`, `type`, `course` and fill them with No if the same combination cannot be found in `df`.

If so, try this:

```py
terms = df["term"].unique()
types = ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]
courses = df["course"].unique()

result = (
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([terms, types, courses], names=["term", "type", "course"])
    .to_frame(index=None)
    .merge(df, on=["term", "type", "course"], how="left")
    .fillna("No")
)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The goal here is to get the missing rows for the combination of `(term, course)` with the new values for `type`. One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to expose the missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.complete(['term', 'course'], {'type': type}, fill_value = 'NO')

   term   type     course offered
0  fall  type1  MATH 1234     Yes
1  fall  type2  MATH 1234     Yes
2  fall  type3  MATH 1234      NO
3  fall  type4  MATH 1234      NO
```

[complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) takes a variable number of arguments - the dictionary allows us to pass in the new values for `type`.